# MySQL Partitioning: why it's not taking appropriate partition

Tags: mysql-5.5

```
          DROP TABLE temp;
          CREATE TABLE `temp` (
         `CallID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
         `InfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
         `CallStartTime` datetime NOT NULL,
         `PartitionID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
         KEY `CallStartTime`(`CallStartTime`)
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
         PARTITION BY HASH (PartitionID)
          PARTITIONS 366
```

I use EXPLAIN in a sample query I get the next result:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM temp where PartitionID = 1
```

or

```
 EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM temp where PartitionID = DAYOFYEAR('2013-01-01 10:24:00')
```

result:

```
   id   select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
  1         SIMPLE          temp    p1  ALL                 2   Using where
```

I don't know why it's using the p1 partition. Here parititon start with p0

Answer (score 2):

The `HASH` partitioning scheme means MySQL translates your arbitrary numerical value into its own hash value. You have defined `366` partitions. What do you think would happen if your query were:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM temp where PartitionID = 400
```

?

Your `PartitionID` cannot mean in this case the real partition's ID/name, since there is no `partition 400`.

Now, just between the two of us, you might be interested to learn that MySQL's `HASH`ing function is a simple modulus. Thus, `0` maps to partition `p0`, `1` maps to partition `p1`, and `400` maps to partition `34` (== `400-366`).

Generally speaking you should not be too interested in the identify of the particular partition being used. You should be more interested to know that there is a good balance of partitions.

If the balance doesn't seem right to you, you might consider using the `KEY` partitioning scheme, where the hashing algorithm is based on a checksum function, which means values are more "randomly" spread as compared to the `HASH` modulus partitioning scheme.